Function that trims intersecting geometries
I want to create plpgsql function that takes columns with id and geometry. Then i want to iterate each row's geometry against all geometries. If row's geometry intersects with all geometries then i want to remove that row from geometries. Next row should be evaluated against all geometries WITHOUT geometry of first row.
What i want
On the image geometries 3,2 and 1 intersect with each other but if i iterate over them and delete geometry with id 1 then geometries with id 4,3 and 2 don't intersect with anything.
What i tried:
create type wynik_fun as 
( 
  pik int,
  geo Geometry
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_intersecting_geometries6(id int, geom geometry)
RETURNS setof wynik_fun AS
$$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
    records wynik_fun;

BEGIN
    DROP TABLE if exists temp_table2;
    DROP TABLE if exists temp_table3;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table2 (
        id2 INT,
        geom2 GEOMETRY
    );
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table3 (
        id3 INT,
        geom3 GEOMETRY
    );
    INSERT INTO temp_table2 (id2, geom2) select id, geom;


    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT id2,geom2 from temp_table2   
        LOOP
        IF ST_Intersects(rec.geom2, geom) and  rec.id2 != id
         THEN
            DELETE FROM temp_table2
            WHERE rec.id2 = id;

         Else
         insert into temp_table3(id3,geom3) values (rec.id2, rec.geom2) ;
        END IF;
        
    END LOOP;
        
   RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM temp_table3;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


Function returns all rows of provided geometries even though i know that some of them intersect.
I expected table with non intersecting geometry. (set of records)
I don't mind if it can be done with CTE.
